# Absorption coefficient from dielectric function

Tags: density-functional-theory, optical-properties

I am aware that one can compute absorption coefficient ($\alpha$) from the dielectric function with the equation $\alpha$ = $(4*pi*k$)/$\lambda$  … (1)

Or from the equation $\alpha$ = k*$\omega$  … (2)

How do I obtain the k and $\lambda$ values so that I can calculate $\alpha$?
I am using the Quantum espresso code

Comment: Welcome to MMSE. Please consider writing equations and mathematical symbols in the MathJax implementation of $LaTeX$ markup. I think it also helps to mention the code you are using for your DFT calculations.

Comment: Musa please make a note of the changes I have made and use similarly in your future que. This is what @Sha was mentioning in his above comment.

Answer (score -1):

The imaginary part (k) of the complex dielectric function and the wavelength (λ) are typically obtained from experimental measurements or theoretical calculations. You can find k and λ values from research papers, databases, or materials characterization tools relevant to your specific material or system. Keep in mind that accurate data sources and appropriate methods are crucial for reliable results.

Here are some databases where you can find dielectric function data, including the imaginary part (k) and wavelength (λ) values:

1. **Palik's Handbook of Optical Constants**: This handbook is a comprehensive source for optical constants, including the complex dielectric function, for a wide range of materials.
2. **Optical Constants of Crystalline and Amorphous Semiconductors**: This database provides optical constants for various semiconductors, including k and λ values.
3. **Ellipsometry Database**: Some ellipsometry databases offer complex dielectric function data for different materials. The J.A. Woollam Database is an example.
4. **NIST Material Data Center**: The National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) provides a collection of material properties, including optical constants, for various materials.
5. **Materials Project**: While primarily focused on computational materials data, the Materials Project may also provide some optical properties information.
6. **Online Material Databases of Universities and Research Institutes**: Many universities and research institutes have online databases that provide optical constants for specific materials or classes of materials.